# @Scheduled annotation Spring

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks, spring-annotations

I am using Spring 3 annotation **@Scheduled** to create scheduled jobs on server. But i am confused about the parameters(**cron**, **fixedDelay** ,**fixedRate**) of @Scheduled annotation. Please explain the **difference** between these parameter and the **situations** in which I can use these parameters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the difference among different options are made clear [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html). It depends on how you need to execute the task:

1. `fixedRate` makes Spring run the task on *periodic* intervals even if the last invocation may be still running.
2. `fixedDelay` specifically controls the next execution time when the last execution finishes.
3. `cron` is a feature originating from Unix cron utility and has various options based on your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

cron : A cron-like expression, extending the usual UN*X definition to include triggers on the second as well as minute, hour, day of month, month and day of week.

fixedDelay : Execute the annotated method with a fixed period between the end of the last invocation and the start of the next.

fixedRate : Execute the annotated method with a fixed period between invocations.

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html